# Getting Errors while installing php on ubuntu16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, apache2, php, php7

Command: `sudo apt-get install php7.0`

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Error: The new file /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production does not exist!
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

While installing libapache2-mod-php7.0

Command: `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0`

Output:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 1 not fully installed or removed.
 After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
 Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
 Error: The new file /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production does not exist!
 dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  libapache2-mod-php7.0
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to resolve this problem.

Comment: Hey. Just a tip to help you out in the future, you can install apt-file: `sudo apt-get install apt-file` then run: `sudo apt-file update` and when you encounter a file such and such is not found like this one, you can find out what package provides a file by running a search for the file like so: `sudo apt-file search /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production` or `sudo apt-file search php.ini-production`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php7.0-common
```

If that doesn't work, run the following commands:

```
mkdir PHP
cd PHP
apt-get download php7.0-common
ar -xvf *
tar -xvf dat*
sudo mv ./usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production
sudo apt-get -f install
```